# How to reuse a case statement in sql

Tags: sql, case

I have a question about reusing the following code in select statement in sql.
I wonder if I can declare a variable for this statement

```
CASE
    WHEN ssr.rating = 'A' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'A[+-]'
    THEN 1

    WHEN ssr.rating = 'AA' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'AA[+-]'
    THEN 2

    WHEN ssr.rating = 'BBB' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'BBB[+-]'
    THEN 3

    ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: You can't really declare a variable for a statement (or part of one) unless you're using dynamic SQL. Could you add a query (and whether you're using MySQL/SQL Server/Oracle/...) and it may still be possible to simplify it.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to use a common table expression to add the column so you can use it later in your query in multiple places;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,
  CASE
    WHEN ssr.rating = 'A' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'A[+-]'     THEN 1
    WHEN ssr.rating = 'AA' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'AA[+-]'   THEN 2
    WHEN ssr.rating = 'BBB' OR ssr.rating LIKE 'BBB[+-]' THEN 3
    ELSE 0
  END value
  FROM ssr
)
SELECT * FROM cte;
```

You can then use `cte` instead of `ssr` in your query and always have the value column added, for example;

```
SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE value=1 OR value=2;
```

...which would otherwise use a case for each comparison.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f69b5/4).

Answer (score 4):

Simpler than a UDF?  I'm not sure what you mean, it is pretty straightforward...

```
CREATE FUNCTION RatingToNumber(@rating nvarchar(10)) RETURNS int AS 
BEGIN
RETURN CASE
    WHEN @rating = 'A' OR @rating LIKE 'A[+-]'     THEN 1
    WHEN @rating = 'AA' OR @rating LIKE 'AA[+-]'   THEN 2
    WHEN @rating = 'BBB' OR @rating LIKE 'BBB[+-]' THEN 3
    ELSE 0
  END 
 END
```

And then you can use it like so...

```
SELECT dbo.RatingToNumber('A')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the output value of this case expression in multiple places within a stored procedure, then yes, absolutely. (are we talking about SQL Server or Oracle?)

Unfortunately, if you are talking about trying tot reuse it in multiple places within a SQL statement, then no, you cannot do that with a T-SQL/P-SQL variable.  To reuse a case expression value in multiple places within a SQL statement, you would have to define and create a User defined function that outputs that case statement value.

Comment: I'm trying to reuse it in SQL server. Is there any simpler ways to do besides create a User Defined Function

Comment: @user2391001 You may be able to use a common table expression, but that would depend on the query.