# How to reuse the same statement within a "select" and a "group by" clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to obtain the domain name of all email address using the string function substring() and charindex(), and then group it and count the number of emails with the same domain name.

**My query:**

```
declare @SearchTerm nvarchar(1) = '@'
select substring(Email, charindex(@SearchTerm, Email) + 1, len(Email)) as [Email Domain],
count(Email) as Total 
from tblResident 
group by substring(Email, charindex(@SearchTerm, Email) + 1, len(Email))
```

But as you can see, the statement used in the "group by" clause is the same as the one I used in "select" statement. It is kind of long and I dont want to write it down twice. So I was just wondering if there is a way I can write `substring(Email, charindex(@SearchTerm, Email) + 1, len(Email))` only once but still achieve the same result?

**My table:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Even if it is long, but it is not wrong.... you can totally write it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reuse a case statement in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593583/how-to-reuse-a-case-statement-in-sql)

Answer (score 3):

```
-- prepare data
use tempdb
drop table dbo.tblResident;
create table dbo.tblResident (id int identity, name varchar(30), Email varchar(30));
go
insert into dbo.tblResident (name, email)
values ('Justin', 'J@J.COM'), ('Nancy', 'N@N.COM'), ('Evee', 'E@E.com'), ('Coco', 'C@C.com'), ('Jess', 'J@J.com');    
go 
-- here is the query
   ;with c as (
    select substring(Email, charindex(@SearchTerm, Email) + 1, len(Email)) as [Email Domain]
    from tblResident )
    select [Email Domain],  Total=count(*)
    from c 
    group by [Email Domain];
```

Comment: Yes, you do not need to write the long substring(Email, charindex(@SearchTerm, Email) + 1, len(Email))  twice.

Comment: Agreed, but it will do no better than @Tony Stark. Of course it will achieve what he wants but from any other aspect what he has done already is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH t AS ( SELECT SUBSTRING(email,3,LEN(email)) AS emaildomain 
FROM tblresident )
SELECT emaildomain,COUNT(*)
FROM t
GROUP BY emaildomain;
```

Comment: I don't believe this is allowed in SQL Server.

Comment: I just want to say the same thing as @siride mentioned here. This simply does not work (in SQL Server), and I do not know why people up-vote it.

Comment: @Teja, I do not think you test your script before you post it here. Even after you modify your original script, this still does not work because there is no LENGTH() function (in sql server)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, if you want J.com once for both J@J.com and K@J.com; means you have to do group by with expression then what you have done is the best way.

On the other hand, if you want J.com twice from J@J.com and K@J.com then you could have do as following;

```
SELECT substring(Email, charindex(@SearchTerm, Email) + 1, len(Email)) as [Email Domain],
COUNT(Email) as Total 
FROM tblResident 
GROUP BY Email
```

Comment: But they are grouping by an expression, which will have a different result than the column by itself.

Comment: @stride, I understand you comment. But this will satisfy the sample data. If it is needed to GROUP BY with expression there is nothing to do with it. I don't understand why down vote !!!!

Comment: And yet common table expression or sub queries could be used but that will do no better than now.

Comment: the sample data may not illustrate every facet of the actual data. It's clear the OP wants to group by the part of an email address after a keyword. Why they want to do this, I don't know, but they do. We have to respect that.

Comment: They literally ask that. They want to group by domain name of email address, which can only be retrieved by expression.

Comment: I don't think stackoverflow is a place to do something literally. Whatever updating my answer.